# Does There exist a particular PSPACE Complete Problem which has a FPTAS algorithm?

Tags: ds.algorithms, space-bounded, big-picture

It is well known that the NP-Complete Problem called Subset Sum has a FPTAS. I was wondering if there existed an PSPACE Complete problem which also has a FPTAS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the answer would be no. 3-partition does not admit FPTAS since it is strongly NP-complete unless P=NP. Also, there is a Karp reduction from 3-partition to any PSPACE-compete problem. Therefore, FPTAS for any PSPACE-complete problem would imply FPTAS for 3-partition which is impossible unless P=NP.

Comment: Karp reduction is an approximation preserving reduction.

Comment: I don't understand - why is Karp reduction approximation-preserving?

Comment: Karp reduction between gap problems preserves approximation results.

Comment: Karp reduction is defined for decision problems, any of approximation-preserving reductions is defined for optimization problems. Therefore, Karp reduction can't be an approximation-preserving reduction.

Comment: @Oleksandr, Have a look at this (http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~safra/Complexity/PCP.pdf)

Comment: @turkistany Thank you for the reference. Now your words make sense for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible to define artificial PSPACE-HARD problems with an FPTAS: define $f(x)=2^{|x|}+g(x)$
where $g(x)$ is a Boolean PSPACE-hard problem whose complexity is at most $2^n$, then $f$ is also PSPACE-hard, but it has an FPTAS: if $\epsilon \gt 2^{-|x|}$ then return $2^{|x|}$ else we have enough time to compute $f$ exactly.

Comment: Could you give a specific (preferably natural) PSPACE-hard problem with $O(2^n)$ time complexity?

Comment: TQBF would do the trick -- input: boolean formula f, output: does there exists x1 such that for all x2 there exists x3 that for all x4 exists ... exists xn such that f(x1....xn).